# Inserting content into TinyMCE using Ipad's built-in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, tinymce

I'm currently using the following simple code to insert content into TinyMCE's editor:

> tinyMCE.get("ole_mce").execCommand("mceInsertContent",false,'hello world!');

It works in every major browser I've tested with, *except* the iPad's built-in one -which is kinda critical for demonstration purposes.

Anyone knows a workaround for this?

Many thanks!

Edit: iPad firmware 4.2.1, tinymce 3.4.2, jquery 1.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use tinyMCE on the iPad at all, since [contenteditable isn't supported there](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html).

Comment: If you're going to answer your own question, at least have the dignity to mark it as community wiki.